# Get / working however get /id not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

Case I:

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping({ "/", "", "/{id}" })
    public List<Product> findProduct(@PathVariable(required = false, name = "id") String id) {
}
```

When accessed

```
http://localhost/api/product - works 
http://localhost/api/product/1 - gives me 404
```

Case II:

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping({ "/", "" })
    public List<Product> findProduct(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "id") String id) {
}
```

When accessed:

```
http://localhost/api/product - works
http://localhost/api/product?id=4 works
```

What am I missing so that `/id` starts working?

I'm using Spring boot 2.6.3.

Comment: Initially, I see no problem. Tried a similar one even with previous Spring Boot version and works fine. If, however, your implementation method is not inside the Controller but in another location, then maybe you should simply add the @PathVariable annotation to the implementation method too, see for example the following answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854834/pathvariable-is-simply-not-working

Comment: my implementation method is in the controller only

Comment: Guess u already did and probably missed in your Copy/Paste, but could you please also add @RestController annotation above RequestMapping("/api/product"), just to make sure Spring Boot gets it 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible in spring boot. You will have to make 2 methods, one with the id and one without

Comment: That's not true. It is indeed a good practice to have a single controller method per path, but it is not a rule or something, RequestMapping, GetMapping do accept multiple mappings.

Comment: yes, but its not possible to have one method with 2 mappings where one has a path variable and one doesn't

Comment: yes u can ..just make the path variable as not required